# How to color ticktext in plotly?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, axis-labels

I would like to display my ticktexts in my plotly xaxis with different colors based on the respective string (based on a dictionary).
Is there a functionality in plotly to do this, maybe via HTML coding?

```
 ticktext = ['<font color="red">{}</font> '.format(x) for x in ticktexts]
```

doesn't work, it gives the html string to the labels.

Comment: Check out [tickcolor](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickcolor) or [tickfont color](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickfont-color)

Comment: tickcolor is used to change the color of the entire axis, as far as I understand. I, however, would like to have the possibility to have different colors in the same axis

Comment: You are right, but I posted a workaround, see answer below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A little bit of a workaround using `LaTeX` can help you here (sorry @Iwileczek, I stole your example, hope you don't mind) because `plotly` has full `LaTeX` [support](https://plot.ly/python/v3/LaTeX/):

```
def color(color, text):
    s = '$\color{' + str(color) + '}{' + str(text) + '}$'
    return s

animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']
ticks = [5, 10, 15, 20]
keys = dict(zip(ticks, colors))

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
ticktext = [color(v, k) for k, v in keys.items()]
print(ticktext)
fig.update_layout(
yaxis=dict(tickmode='array', ticktext=ticktext, tickvals=ticks)
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

---

**Update March 2021**:

If you don't want to use the `LaTex` rendered font by `MathJax` in your output, use the solution of @Dapcer with an HTML styling:

```py
def color(color, text):
    return f"<span style='color:{str(color)}'> {str(text)} </span>"
```

Example with `fig.update_layout(font=dict(family="Times New Roman") [...]`:
[image]

Comment: I would call this a solution rather than a workaround!

Comment: [Didn't worked for me, unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477108/individually-color-side-ticks-of-a-plotly-graph-objects-bar) the LaTex text comes out in its encoded format rather than colored one.

Comment: It works for me and is a brilliant answer, but the latex shows up as a different font than the rest of the text. The latex seems to be treating the text in equation style, rather than text style. I tried adding `\text{...}` around it, but that didn't work. I'm having trouble finding latex that is valid that treats the text as normal text rather than equation text.

Comment: @DavidParks You can use @Dapcer's solution with `return "<span style='color:" + str(color) + "'>" + str(text) + "</span>"` as the `color` function, this gives you the same font as the rest. Because `MathJax` (which is used to render the `Latex` in plolty), only supports very limited to near no other fonts... see [link](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html)

Answer (score 10):

**HTML alternative to Albo's solution:**

I used [Albo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58187376/5698098) and replaced Latex code with HTML code. Same solution but avoiding Latex fonts if you are not inserting Math symbols.

Just replace Latex code from

```
def color(color, text):
    s = '$\color{' + str(color) + '}{' + str(text) + '}$'
    return s
```

to HTML code

```
def color(color, text):
    # color: hexadecimal
    s = "<span style='color:" + str(color) + "'>" + str(text) + "</span>$"
    return s
```

Answer (score 6):

### Please see Albo's answer!

---

You can change to a single color by updating the `color` property of the `yaxis` or `xaxis`.  The color property must be a single color as it only accepts strings that decode to colors. However, you can update the `ticktext` property of charts with Latex formatting to accomplish this. Please see Albo's answer to learn how to do this.

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

    fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
    fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(color="#E90")

    )
    fig.show()
```

[image]

#### Documentation

- [y-axis color](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-color)
- [tick text](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext)
- [Plotly & LaTex](https://plot.ly/pandas/LaTeX/) (slightly out of date)