# Draw scatter plot with two nominal variables with Plotly package in R

Tags: r, r-plotly

The question is how to draw following plot using Plotly package in R?

[image]

I have a dataframe  with 166 columns. I should use a loop for plot all the columns. I try as follows:

```
  X1<-rep(c("A","B"),each=4)
  X2<-rep(letters[1:4],len=length(X1))
  Y1<-c(1, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.8, 1.7, 1.5, 1.6)
  Y2<-Y1^2;Y3<-log(Y1)
  data_f<-data.frame(X1=X1,X2=X2,Y1=Y1,Y2=Y2,Y3=round(Y3,2))
  plt <- plot_ly()%>%
  layout(title = "",
     xaxis = list(title = ""),
     yaxis = list (title = "") )


 for( i in 3:dim(data_f)[2]){
 text1<-paste0('X1 : ', data_f$X1, '\n',
            'X2 : ', data_f$X2, '\n',
            'Y1 : ', data_f$Y1, '\n',
            'Y2 : ', data_f$Y2, '\n',
            'Y3 : ', data_f$Y3 
 )

plt<-plt %>% add_trace(x=paste(data_f$X1,data_f$X2)
                               ,y=data_f[,i],
                               type='scatter',
                               mode='line+markers',
                               line=list( width = 4),
                               marker=list(size=15),
                               text =text1,
                               hoverinfo = 'text'
                               
    )  
  }
  plt
```

and the outcome is as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
plt <- plot_ly(data = data_f,
               x=~ list(X1, X2))%>%
  layout(title = "Chart Title",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list (title = ""),
         hovermode="x unified")

for(i in 3:5){
  plt <- plt %>%
    add_trace(y= data_f[,i],
              mode='lines+markers',
              type = "scatter",
              name = colnames(data_f)[i])
}


plt
```

Multicategorical axis (x-axis with two levels) can be set with `x =~ list(X1, X2)`. And a combinded hovertemplate can the achieved through  `hovermode="x unified"`.

**Plot**
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to assign different color to each categories. For example the color of first "a b c d" be red and other be blue?

Comment: Different colors for tickfont are not implemented in plolty. There are workarounds  with `ticktext` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183962/how-to-color-ticktext-in-plotly),  but I don't know if you can transfer this to multicategorial axis.